# C++ Stream: Insert string after newline

Tags: c++, stream

The raw question is: How do you autoinsert something into a stream after a newline has occured. The insertion should only happend if something is inserted (manually) into the stream afterwards.

Below follows a more detailed explanation.

---

For exercise I'm writing my own logger class. The basic logging functionality is given by this snippet.

```c++
class Logger {
public:
    static std::ostream & log( LogLevels::LogLevel level );
};

// Use it:
Logger::log( LogLevels::WARNING ) << "Something serious happened!" << std::endl;
```

The example prints something like

```
[ WARNING: 0 ] Something serious happened!
```

I would like to extend this functionality such that after insertion of a newline into the stream all debug messages are indented by the width of the *logging header* until `Logger::log` is called again. This is best explained by showing an example:

```c++
// Example (1)
Logger::log( LogLevels::WARNING ) << "Something happened!" 
                                  << std::endl 
                                  << "Some More information: " 
                                  << 42 
                                  << " (Still on the same line)"
                                  << std::endl;

Logger::log( LogLevels::INFO ) << "Merely a status code"
                               << std::endl
                               << "Which reads: " 
                               << 21 
                               << " (Also on the same line)"
                               << std::endl;

// Example (2)
std::ostream & os = Logger::log( LogLevels::WARNING );
os << "First line"
   << std::endl;

os << "Second line"
   << std::endl;

// Example (3)
// [...]
// Some code is executed
Logger::log( LogLevels::WARNING ) << "A new error" 
                                  << std::endl 
                                  << "The code strikes back"
                                  << std::endl 
                                  << "The return of the bugs"
                                  << std::endl ;
```

Which would yield:

```
[ WARNING: 0 ] Something hapened!  
               Some More information: 42 (Still on the same line)
[ INFO: 1 ] Merely a status code
            Which reads: 21 (Also on the same line)
[ WARNING: 2 ] First line
               Second line
// [...]
[ WARNING: 99998 ] A new error
                   The code strikes back
                   The return of the bugs
```

**Can this behaviour achieved and if so, how?**

Comment: http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/

Comment: It doesn't seem like this would be a very intuitive interface.

Comment: @BoBTFish `s/std::endl/'\n'/g` My question is not about using `std::endl` and I'm well aware of the speed difference. However I think in example code like this using `std::endl` makes it much more readable.

Comment: @JosephMansfield And why is that? This interface creates _blocks_ of log messages. A new block is started by a new call to `Logger::log`.

Comment: @elemakil Because that's not the same behaviour as other streams in C++.

Comment: @elemakil, there is a block of log message only in your brain. log() call returns std::ostream& and every time you use `<<` operator you actually call `std::ostream::operator<<(...)`, so here is a chaining call. You can't say for sure where is the new block start.

Comment: @maverik Yes, that is the case in the current setup. My first idea how to obtain the intended interface was to return a `ostream_block` which collects the log messages (well aware of blocks) and inserts them into the actual `ostream` on destruction (should have added that to question). But I don't know how that `ostream_block` can inspect the items streamed into it and form the correct lines from that inspection.

Comment: @maverik You can if you do it right.  See my answer.

Comment: @BoBTFish This is one point where I disagree with Dietmar.  Using `'\n'` instead of `std::endl` makes debugging the code a lot harder, and in a lot of cases, doesn't make any real difference in the total time.  (If it does, of course, there's always time to reconsider.)  This case is very particular, of course: you want exactly one flush at the end of each record.  My solution involves a `streambuf` with a conceptually infinite buffer, which ignores the usual `sync`, but has a separate function called by the destructor of the logging object, which ensures the proper, atomic flush.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm not qualified to comment on your solution, but my personal objection isn't really about speed. I don't want to put words in Dietmar's mouth, but last time I spoke to him about this, he more or less agreed with me: I make "don't use `endl`" a simple rule, because it is so often misunderstood and misused (I wouldn't accuse you of this) that when you read it in code it is impossible to know what the original author meant. Also, the content of the text and the behaviour of the stream really have nothing to do with each other. So I prefer to flush explicitly.

Comment: (And he is always quick to tell people that he has seen real production issues due to overzealous use of `std::endl`)

Comment: @BoBTFish The problem is that the people who don't understand the flushing issues are precisely the ones who need the flush; if the program crashes, they'll look at what's left in the file, and start debugging from there.  Flushing is never "wrong" (except from a performance point of view); not flushing sometimes is (in the case of a log file, for example).  So if you're going to tell beginners to use only one, it has to be flushing.  Afterwards... I'm not really a beginner, and in my own code, I will switch from one to the other, depending on circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Just insert a filtering streambuf between the ostream and the
final target streambuf.  Something like the following should do
the trick:

```
class HeaderInserter : public std::streambuf
{
    std::streambuf* myDest;
    bool myIsAtStartOfLine;
protected:
    int overflow( int ch ) override
    {
        int retval = 0;
        if ( ch != traits_type::eof() ) {
            if ( myIsAtStartOfLine ) {
                std::string header = getHeader();
                myDest->sputn( header.data(), header.size() );
            }
            retval = myDest->sputc( ch );
            myIsAtStartOfLine = ch == '\n';
        }
        return retval;
    }
public:
    HeaderInserter( std::streambuf* dest )
        : myDest( dest )
        , myIsAtStartOfLine( true )
    {
    }
};
```

Create one of these, with a pointer to your final destination
(`std::cerr.rdbuf()`, or an `std::filebuf` which you've opened),
then use an `std::ostream` which points to it.

I use this in my own logger classes; I add additional functions
to start and finish a new logger record: the first output after
starting a record outputs a time stamp, plus the `__FILE__` and
`__LINE__` that I've transmitted down; the following headers are
simply an arbitrary amount of white space, to indent.  And the
finish function will also ensure that the record ends with
a `'\n'`, and is flushed.

Finally, some more general comments: first, you don't want the
client code to call `Logger::log`, but rather some macro, in
order to automatically pass `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` into the
actual object created.  The object itself should probably be
a temporary, whose destructor calls the finish routine above.
And finally, if you're in a multithreaded environment, you'll
probably want to target a `streambuf` with a practically
unlimited buffer (an `std::vector<char>`, for example), which
ignores any flush from the user, and then does whatever is
necessary to atomically write the entire buffer when the finish
routine is called, ensuring, of course, that each thread has its
own instance of all of the above components.  (If you're on
a Unix platform, for example, the Posix function `write` is
guaranteed atomic, so you won't need any locks.)

Answer (score 1):

I think a more intuitive interface would be:

```
Logger::log( LogLevels::WARNING ) << "Something happened!" 
    << Logger::tabbedLine 
    << "More Info";
```

And so the user can still use `'\n'` or `std::endl` to get to the start of the next line, or use `Logger::tabbedLine` (a bad name, I admit) to achieve what you want.

You can subclass `std::ostream` and add an overload for `operator<<` which receives a special class which `tabbedLine` is a static instance of this type. You will need to 'remember' the required padding in this stream subclassing that you create.

`Logger::log` will return the instance of this `ostream` subclass.

Comment: I have a similar solution in place (no subclassing of `std::ostream`, `Logger` has a static `std::string` member `pad_newline` which inserts the appropriate padding). However, using this solution the user has to remember to pick the correct newline for the last item to be inserted (the one without padding), right?

Comment: As a general rule, this is one place where you want to use a macro, in order to automatically insert `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.

Comment: @elemakil - usually in loggers, the user doesn't add the newline after the message - the logger should do so automatically (so `Logger::log(INFO) << "Started";` will add a newline).

Comment: @JamesKanze - true in general for loggers.

Comment: @JamesKanze That's why I have a `LogVerbose(streamtext)` macro which wraps around `Logger::log` and inserts in addition to the `streamtext` the function name, file and lineno.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a own stream , stream buffer and manipulators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

// LogBuffer
// ============================================================================

class LogBuffer : public std::streambuf
{
    // Types
    // =====

    public:
    typedef typename std::streambuf buffer_type;
    typedef typename buffer_type::char_type char_type;
    typedef typename buffer_type::traits_type traits_type;
    typedef typename buffer_type::int_type int_type;
    typedef typename buffer_type::pos_type pos_type;
    typedef typename buffer_type::off_type off_type;

    // Construction/Destructiion
    // =========================

    public:
    LogBuffer(buffer_type& buffer)
    :   m_buffer(buffer), m_indent(0), m_warning_count(0)
    {}

    public:
    ~LogBuffer() {
        m_buffer.pubsync();
    }

    private:
    LogBuffer(LogBuffer const&); // No Copy.
    LogBuffer& operator=(LogBuffer const&); // No Copy.


    // Functionality
    // =============

    public:
    bool write(const std::string& s) {
        return m_buffer.sputn(s.data(), s.size()) == std::streamsize(s.size());
    }

    bool warning() {
        std::ostringstream out;
        out << "[ WARNING: " << m_warning_count++ << "] ";
        m_indent = out.str().size();
        return write(out.str());
    }
    bool insert_indent() {
        std::ostringstream out;
        out << std::setw(m_indent) << "";
        return write(out.str());
    }

    // Virtuell
    // ========

    protected:
    std::streamsize xsputn(const char_type* s, std::streamsize n) {
        return m_buffer.sputn(s, n);
    }

    int_type overflow(int_type ch) {
        if(ch == traits_type::eof()) return traits_type::eof();
        else return m_buffer.sputc(traits_type::to_char_type(ch));
    }

    int sync() {
        return m_buffer.pubsync();
    }

    private:
    buffer_type& m_buffer;
    unsigned m_indent;
    unsigned m_warning_count;
};



// LogStream
// ============================================================================

class LogStream : public std::ostream
{
    // Types
    // =====

    private:
    typedef std::ostream Base;
    typedef LogBuffer buffer_type;

    public:
    typedef std::ostream stream_type;
    typedef typename Base::char_type char_type;
    typedef typename Base::traits_type traits_type;
    typedef typename Base::int_type int_type;
    typedef typename Base::pos_type pos_type;
    typedef typename Base::off_type off_type;

    // Construction
    // ============

    public:
    LogStream()
    :   Base(&m_buffer), m_buffer(*std::clog.rdbuf())
    {}

    LogStream(stream_type& stream)
    :   Base(&m_buffer), m_buffer(*stream.rdbuf())
    {}

    private:
    LogStream(const LogStream&); // No copy.
    const LogStream& operator = (const LogStream&); // No copy.

    private:
    buffer_type m_buffer;
};



// Manipulator
// ===========

std::ostream& log_warning(std::ostream& stream) {
    LogBuffer* buffer = dynamic_cast<LogBuffer*>(stream.rdbuf());
    if(buffer) {
        if( ! buffer->warning())
            stream.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    return stream;
}


std::ostream& log_indent(std::ostream& stream) {
    LogBuffer* buffer = dynamic_cast<LogBuffer*>(stream.rdbuf());
    if(buffer) {
        if( ! buffer->insert_indent())
            stream.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    return stream;
}


int main() {
    LogStream log;
    log << log_warning
        << "First\n"
        << log_indent
        << "Second\n"
        << std::flush;
}
```